# Creating executable file with R: How to keep GUI open running Rscript

Tags: r, user-interface, executable, rscript

I made a GUI using R, and I wanted to make an executable file for it, so other people can double click and launch the GUI without seeing any R code. I made a .bat file and have Rscript run my R code, but what happened is that the GUI is created and then closed, so I cannot interact with the GUI at all. So I want
to ask for any suggestion on how to make the GUI stay open until I close it? Or any other ways to make an executable file? Thanks!

BTW, I am using windows 7.